# Creating a sparse matrix from pandas data frame using scipy.sparse

Tags: python, pandas, scipy

I am having a pandas dataframe (approximately 1M rows) with two variables X and Y and would want to create a sparse matrix using scipy,sparse. The output should be a n x m matrix whose entries are 1 if X = x and Y = y.
Below is an example of the data structure

```
import pandas as pd
data = [[1256, 10], [3087, 15], [2199, 14], [2199, 10], [1256, 15], [3087, 14], [1056, 10], [408, 15], [1256, 14]]
  
# Create the pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['X', 'Y'])
  
# print dataframe.
df
```

The desired output is

```
       10  15  14
1256    1   1   1
3087    0   1   0
2199    1   0   1
3087    0   0   1
1056    1   0   0
408     0   1   0
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have two rows `3087` in your output, could you explain why?

Comment: Sorry that was a mistake from my end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `get_dummies` with `sparse=True` and maybe use `dtype='i8'` (optional) for less memory use

```
out = pd.get_dummies(df.set_index("X")['Y'],sparse=True,dtype='i8').max(level=0)
```

---

```
print(out)


      10  14  15
X               
1256   1   1   1
3087   0   1   1
2199   1   1   0
1056   1   0   0
408    0   0   1
```

Comment: This is super cool. Thanks so  much for taking time and helping me out

Comment: @StephenOkiya if the answer helped you, please consider accepting the answer so as to close this question..!! [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)

Comment: While the answer is in general right. The code has taken hours and its still running.